# Restringir la apertura de mas de 1 frame JAVA

Tags: java

estaría necesitando que solo pueda abrirse una sola vez esa instancia, y a su vez cuando esta se cierre se pueda volver a abrir.

```
  private void credencialActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           


    if (bandera == false) {

        gu = new gestionUsuarios();
        gu.setVisible(true);
        bandera = true;

    }




}
```

Ese codigo me permite que solo la instancia pueda ser abierta una vez. Pero cuando la cierro y la quiero volver a abrir no me permite.

Comment: donde se vuelve a poner bandera en false?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que cuando pongo la bandera en false de vuelta se siguen abriendo las ventanas de vuelta

Comment: hay que ponerla en false, cuando se cierra esta.. alguien en algun momento la tiene que poner en false. y ese momento, es cuando esta se cierra.

Comment: Si la pongo en false afuera del if es lo mismo que nada. Básicamente va a preguntar: es false? Luego abre y pone la bandera en true. Después pones afuera del if el false. Que pasa, cuando vuelves a presionar bandera va a volver a ser false y se va a abrir de vuelta. Es lo mismo que nada.

Comment: no.. a ver.. nadie te esta diciendo que lo pongas ahi. Cuando se cierra esa ventana, ocurre un evento de cerrado. Ahi es donde deberias poner esa bandera devuelta en false. Estamos hablando de eventos que ocurren con la ventana, y vos tenes que avisar que no hay mas ventana cuando se cerro, no en cualquier momento...

Comment: Mmm es cierto, voy a probarlo.

Comment: Tenias razón. Te agradezco mucho.